# How to remove the link from the logo in Oracle Apex 5.1 Universal Theme

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm working on a project in Oracle Apex 5.1 with Universal Theme. We need the logo (actually, an image), but want to remove the hyperlink from it.
I tried custom css by  setting the class t-Header-logo (and t-Header-logo-link, too) to "pointer-event:none" (in Theme Toller), but it does not work. Can anyone help?
Thanks: Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use below jquery code for removing link from logo
Put this code on page zero. It will work you whole application across.

```
$(".t-Header-logo a").removeAttr("href")
```